# Pintos - UserProg all tests fail is_kernel_vaddr()

Tags: pintos

I am doing the Pintos project on the side to learn more about operating systems. I had tons of devops trouble at first with it not running well on an 18.04 Ubuntu droplet. I am now running it on the VirtualBox image that UCCS tells students to download for pintos.

I finished project 1 and started to map out my solution to project 2. Following the instructions to create a file I ran

```
pintos-mkdisk filesys.dsk --filesys-size=2
pintos -- -f -q
```

but am getting error

```
Kernel PANIC at ../../threads/vaddr.h:87 in vtop(): assertion 
`is_kernel_vaddr (vaddr)' failed.
```

I then tried running make check (all the tests). They are all failing for the same reason.

Am I missing something? Is there something I need to implement to fix this? I reread the instructions and didnt see anything?

Would appreciate help!
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. My code for Project 1 ran fine, but I could not format the filesystem for Project 2.

The failure for me came from the following call chain:

`thread_init()` -> ... -> `thread_schedule_tail()` -> `process_activate()` -> `pagedir_activate()` -> `vtop()`

The problem is that `init_page_dir` is still NULL when `pagedir_activate()` is called. `init_page_dir` should have been initialized in `paging_init()` but this is called after `thread_init()`.

The root cause was that my scheduler was being called too early, i.e. before the call to `thread_start()`. The reason for my problem was that I had built in a call to `thread_yield()` upon completion of every call to `lock_release()` which makes sense from a priority donation standpoint. Unfortunately, locks are used prior to the scheduler being ready! To fix this, I installed a flag called `threading_started` that bails in the first line of my `thread_block()` and `thread_yield()` functions if `thread_start()` has not yet been called.

Good luck!

Comment: This helped me find the answer! I was calling thread_yield() every time in sema_down(), the early preemption screwed everything up. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck with the next project! I just started working on supporting user programs yesterday.

Comment: Finished the project yet? :) Im working on filesystems right now, I added logic for extensible files and am just debugging. Great project. Thanks for the help early on. I gave you upvotes on both but It doesn't show since my account is new. Cheers

Comment: Oh geeze. I'm not a fan of the StackOverflow policies for new members, especially for these types of somewhat obscure questions. To answer your question, I finished supporting user programs, and now I'm working on virtual memory. It's taking me a bit to figure out how to get started, but I'll probably knock it out over the next few weekends.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Charles Celerier's answer, this worked for me.

Define `thread_try_yield` such as

```c
void thread_try_yield(void) {
  if (!list_empty(&ready_list) && thread_current() != idle_thread)
    thread_yield();
}
```

and call it rather than calling `thread_yield()` directly.